# $_SESSION: variable not carrying over to other php page

Tags: php, mysql, session

So basically I'm programming a form that passes data from index.php to highscore.php. To stop spammers that click on the submit button repetitively, I have added a system where index.php creates a uniqid and sets it as a session variable as well as posting it with the rest of the form. highscores.php receives the posted uniqid and compares it to the session variable. If it matches, it adds the data and unsets the session variable, thereby stopping all of the other posts it gets because the uniqid doesn't match anymore

However, the `$_SESSION['form_token']` is not a valid index on the highscores.php page. I'm not sure what's going wrong...

Here is my code:

index.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    $form_token = uniqid();

    $_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
    echo $_SESSION['form_token'];
?>
```

highscore.php

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['form_token'];
```

The echo on the last line doesn't print anything.

If you need more code, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:** Running `print_r($_SESSION)` on index.php has returned:

```
    56a741da4bcc7Array
(
    [form_token] => 56a741da4bcc7
)
```

on highscores.php it returns

```
Array()
```

Also, on the index.html, the `echo $_SESSION['form_token']` does return the uniqid...

**EDIT 2:** I've been experimenting with it, and i found out that if I reload index.php then submit the form, it works fine. Otherwise, it seems to not work...

Thanks again!

Comment: Does your browser keeps the session cookie, have you check it via F12 ? Does your web server can create session files on your server ? Does this issue occurs on your development environment or production environment ? @demar

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) , in each page , and change your browser and tell what you see.

Comment: Is start session_start(); the first line of code?

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['form_token'])) { echo  $_SESSION['form_token']; }

Comment: Does the echo on the index page show a value?

Comment: *"To stop spammers that click on the submit button repetitively, I have added a system where index.php creates a uniqid and sets it as a session variable..."* - so, to spam the form I simply need tell my browser not to accept cookies then?

Comment: @CihanUygun, what do you mean by checking it via f12? I'm on a mac, and f12 doesn't do anything for me... is that inspect element or something?

Comment: Do you destroy session anywhere in your application?

Comment: @demar I mean developer console for **Chrome** Resources->Cookies section and for **Firefox** Storage->Cookies you should see same session cookie between pages

Comment: have you shown the whole code? Don't you have some if ($_POST exists) {} around this code?